# RTL Icon Positions in Android Drawer

Tags: java, android

I wanna move the Icons to the right side of the drawer , like below picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Fix issue description. Just use proper item xml that is inflated in adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically that is automatically handled by the layout manager when the user's chosen language is RTL (as in your screenshot).  In your layouts, make sure you use the "Start" and "End" attributes (as opposed to Left and Right) for proper support of RTL languages.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html